# Two Circles tangent to diameter and a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

[image]

Sorry for bad drawing. In order to find $PQ$ I draw radiuses $r_1$ and $r_2$ and according to image $PQ$ is equal to white line which is equal to

$$\sqrt{(r_1+r_2)^2-(r_1-r_2)^2}=2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$$

But I don't know how to find $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Edit:

Here is original image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Distance between centers of two smaller circles is not $r_1 + r_2$. In fact $PQ = r_1 + r_2$. Can you please draw a better diagram and label the points?

Comment: @MathLover I just added original image. center of smaller circles aren't displayed, so I'm not sure about the correct drawing.

Comment: @MathLover is correct. Notice that the smaller circles are not touching and that there is a vertical line separating them.

Comment: Can anyone please say whether the two smaller circles are tangent at a common point or not?

Comment: See also: [Circle problem in which I wanted to find value of $PQ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3136052).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two circles are not in contact; $PQ \neq 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\,$ but actually $PQ=r_1+r_2$.

Let's name the blue circle $C$, its center $X$, its tangent point with the large circle $Y$ and the intersection point of $PQ$ and the vertical line $H$.

Let the radius of $C$ be $r$, then $XY=PX=PH=r$.

$$OY=10 \Rightarrow OX=10-r$$
$$OH=10-\frac{36}{5}=\frac{14}{5} \Rightarrow PO=r+\frac{14}{5}$$
$$ PX^2+PO^2=OX^2 \Rightarrow r^2+(r+\frac{14}{5})^2=(10-r)^2 \Rightarrow r=\frac{16}{5} $$

Using a similar method, the radius of the green circle is $\frac{24}{5}$.

Therefore, $PQ=8$.

Comment: Superb! I did not spot that $OXY$ is a straight line...